# unable to access memory 0X.... C program (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: c, memory

Purpose of code:
TO maintain a unique element link list...UFID is the keyword for unique

```
Structure declaration:

    struct sharedFiles
    {
      char UFID[50];
      int valid;                    //valid 1 if someone have this file in write mode
      int shared;                   //no of user's reading this file
      struct sharedFiles *next;     //pointer to next node
    }*sfstart,*sfend;               //sfstart points to the first node of linked list and efend to the last node of linked list so that it will be easy to just insert at the end without traversing the linked list
```

Error Description:
The below code gives segmentation fault when I invoking it 2nd time.
I tried to debug with GDB and it says unable to access the location at line

```
if(strcmp(sftemp->UFID,ufid)==0)
```

In the above line it is unable to access **sftemp->UFID**

```
/*Function code*/


  int addShareList(char *ufid,int mode)      //mode=0 (read)  and mode=1 (Write request)
{
  struct sharedFiles *sftemp,*newnode;

  sftemp=sfstart;
   if(sfstart==NULL)   //if list is empty add first node
   {
       sfstart=(struct sharedFiles *) malloc(sizeof(struct sharedFiles));
       strcpy(sfstart->UFID,ufid);
       sfstart->valid=mode;
       sfstart->shared=1;
       sfstart->next=NULL;
       sfend=sfstart;             //this node will also be last node of Linked list
       return 0;
   }
   else                 //if list is not empty
   {

        while(sftemp->next != NULL)    //traverse till last node
        {
          if(strcmp(sftemp->UFID,ufid)==0)
          {
             //here if same node found some manupulation to the struct variables

          }
         sftemp=sftemp->next;
        } //while


  if(sftemp->next==NULL)  //procvess last node
       {

         if(strcmp(sftemp->UFID,ufid)!=0) //if last node not same add node at the end of   Linked list
         {
           newnode=(struct sharedFiles *) malloc(sizeof(struct sharedFiles));
           strcpy(newnode->UFID,ufid);
           newnode->valid=mode;
           newnode->shared=1;
            newnode->next=NULL;
           sftemp->next=newnode;
           sfend=newnode;
           return 0;
          }
          else //if last node is same
          {

                //some manipulations to struct variables 
          }
       } //if


   }

return -1;
}//addShareList
```

The above code works fine for inserting first element.When I invoke the same function for inserting second node in the linked list it unable to access the first node while comarision
in the line if(strcmp(sftemp->UFID,ufid)==0). Hope now the purpose of code is clear.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: sfstart->shared=1;
       sftemp->next=NULL;  I have corrected this mistake it should be  sfstart->shared=1;
       sfstart->next=NULL;

Comment: This code can't be run. Names are meaningless. No comments. `sfstart` is global. It's not even clear what's the purpose of this function. How do you expect we guess why `sftemp->UFID` is null? Please, improve your question

Comment: @ Raffaele: I have modified the question please take a look now..

Comment: Can you please post the calling code? If it's too long, make a gist. Also, the meaning of the first line of your question is ambiguous: do you mean that this function appends the file to the list only if the list itself does not yet contain a file with the same id?

Comment: @user2123967 I said you, initialize ***sfstart** = NULL when you declare it, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner it was really silly mistake as you pointed...I have initialized sfstart and sfend to NULL and seems that the problem is resolved..But can you explain why there is need to initialize that to NULL. later in the program I have  allocated memory for that so why there is need to initialize it to NULL.. :(

Comment: @user2123967 First of all, it's good that now it works ;)
The problem was that in the first iteration it didn't enter into the _if(sfstart==NULL)_, because when you declare a variable it has a dirty value and not NULL. You must initialize it with the value you want, in your case **NULL**.
Please, if I solved your problem set my answer as the solution answer, this way other users will immediately know what to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *while* you check if **sftemp!=NULL** so we can be sure that in the second iteration, after line **sftemp=sftemp->next;** the pointer contain allocated memory.

But, since I don't know how the list it structured, I can't be sure that the content contains another node of *sharedFiles* type, it could contain an **end-list node** which not contains *UFID* attribute.

So, check in your list how to control if the list is finished.

Another solution can be to change your check this way:

```
while(sftemp->next!=NULL)

...

if(sftemp->next==NULL) {
    //add the node in the right way, consider the end-list node
}
```

EDIT:

Furthermore, change in the first **if** the line *sftemp->next = NULL;* to *sfnext->next = NULL;*.

And be sure to initialize **stnext** = NULL.

EDIT 2:

Now that you post struct declaration I still cannot see when you initialize **sfstart**. Try to do this:

```
Structure declaration:

struct sharedFiles
{
  char UFID[50];
  int valid;                    //valid 1 if someone have this file in write mode
  int shared;                   //no of user's reading this file
  struct sharedFiles *next;     //pointer to next node
}*sfstart = NULL,*sfend;
```

Comment: Still same error :Breakpoint 1, addShareList (ufid=0x606240 <arrufid> "1270011583993", mode=0) at server1.c:1193
1193         while(sftemp->next != NULL)
(gdb) print sfstart->UFID
Cannot access memory at address 0x5f745f735f695f6c
(gdb) print sftemp->next
Cannot access memory at address 0x5f745f735f695fac

Comment: @user2123967 Have you changed from _sftemp->next=NULL;_ to _sfnext->next=NULL;_ in the first **if**?
And be sure to initialize at **NULL** sfnext pointer.

Comment: @user2123967 Please, if I solved your problem remember to set mine as the solution answer (click on the empty check on the left of my answer). This way other users will immediately know what to see.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the answer for this is that the pointer is NULL, which in your case means `malloc` has failed because you're out of memory - you really should be checking the return value.

The most likely cause for your problem is that you have corrupted the heap, so that `sftemp` no longer points to a valid memory address. Check what it's value is that might give you some more clues.

Comment: But it successfully allocates memory ...The error occurs when I am trying to access the previously allocated element of link list.. :(

Comment: @user2123967 Please, if I solved your problem remember to set my answer as the solution answer. In this way other users will immediately know what to see